# LSM6DS33 how to filter accelerometer values even more (< 50Hz)

Tags: accelerometer, st

I'm trying to use a LSM6DS33 6-axis accelerometer/gyro chip as an inertial navigation aid, participating in sensor fusion. The problem is that the application has large amount of vibrations and the accelerometer data is quite noisy. I need around 25 accelerometer samples per second, so to get a smoother signal I have enabled the analog low-pass filter at the lowest BW = 50Hz and the accelerometer ODR is 104 Hz; I average 4 samples manually whilst reading them to get equivalent ODR of 26 Hz with less aliasing.

This is better than before (when there was no low-pass and at 52 Hz ODR), but there's still some noise (around 0.1g peak-to-peak - measured on a vibrating platform that vibrates at ~65 Hz) present in the resulting averaged samples. I verified that increasing the accelerometer ODR to 208 Hz decreases noise (aliasing) further. 416Hz reduces it even further (0.025g p-p). But that needs more I²C traffic and CPU time, so increasing the ODR will be prohibitive.

My question is: is it possible to set up the LSM6DS33 to sample the accelerometer at 833 Hz, average each 8 samples, and put the results in the FIFO (equivalent 104 ODR)? Or put in other way, to get an equivalent low-pass filtering BW lower than 50 Hz, ideally around 12 Hz?

For reference, my current config is:

> CTRL1_XL = 0x4F; // acc setup -> 104 Hz, 8 g full scale, 50Hz bandwidth
>
> CTRL2_G = 0x4C; // gyro setup -> 104 Hz, 2000 dps full scale
>
> CTRL3_C = 0x44;  // set BDU (block data update) bit high
>
> CTRL4_C = 0x81;  // enable FIFO length limit; XL_BW_SCAL_ODR=1
>
> ... (and also some unrelated code for setting up the FIFO).

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you?

Comment: Average 8 samples at ODR 104 Hz then? I don't see any facility in the LSM to do averaging or accumulating any samples.

Comment: @Andyaka, the datasheet mentions data can be decimated, but I don't know how's that defined, it can be "take each n-th sample" or "average n samples", and the datasheet is sparse on that.
The bigger problem is that the datasheet says "*It’s required to set at least one of the three decimation factors to 1 (no decimation).*", which means if I set 833 ODR, at least one channel MUST be at 833 ODR, which is too much I²C traffic for me.

Comment: @Arsenal, I want to do digital low-pass filtering by averaging a lot of incoming samples, e.g. the accelerometer is at 833 Hz ODR, average every 8 incoming readings to get 104 samples/s equivalent. Or average 32 incoming readings to get 26 samples/s, very well filtered.

Comment: @Arsenal, I slightly misunderstood your comment. I'm averaging 4 samples at 104 Hz already, but the remaining noise is too much. 8 samples at 104 Hz will give insufficient output data rate.

Comment: Can you change the hardware to be fast enough to handle the data rate, or do you have to use a specific CPU?  You could also add a small external CPLD to do the reading and averaging for you, independent of the CPU.  You could even do this with a CPLD evaluation board so that it could be prototyped.

Comment: @crj11, yes, this is an option, but adds cost and at some point I might just use a different IMU chip that has low-pass filters lower than 50 Hz

Comment: Is a IIR-filter structure completely out of the realm of possibilities? I find those easy to implement and quite effective. They can also be made adaptive to get better step responses compared to a fixed IIR filter. And even if you take an average of 8 samples that doesn't mean you have to reduce the output data rate to 1/8th if you take the average of the last 8 values.

Comment: I can also filter the data in post-processing; same thing essentially. But I'm not satisfied by that. What I'm getting are aliasing errors. I'm feeding a 60 Hz vibration to a device that outputs 25 samples per second, and I'm getting a signal out - that's what I want to eliminate if possible. My suspicion is that the 50Hz analog filter is not very steep, probably just one or two RC groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [confirmed](https://community.st.com/thread/48068-lsm6ds33-how-to-filter-accelerometer-values-even-more-50hz) by STM staff, the functionality I was requesting is not possible with this chip.

For reference, I'm considering the [ICM-20602](https://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/.../DS-000176-ICM-20602-v1.0.pdf) which sports both lower filtering cutoff options, and the possibility to do on-chip averaging.